# SVG letters can not evenly spaced

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I position each letter with 0, 12, 24, 36 etc... on x axis. I am expecting each letter will be spaced evenly, but they are not.

```
const websiteName = "websitename".split('');

<svg width="180" height="36" style={{display:"block"}}>
    {                  
       [...websiteName].map((letter, i) => (
           <text x={i*12} y="30" fontSize="22" key={i}>{letter}</text>
       ))
                    }
</svg>
```

Here is how it look like:

[image]

What is the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: Remember to center-align your `<text>`, right now they're all left-aligned.

Comment: They **are** all evenly spaced, but in this font -- like most fonts -- the letters are not of equal width.  You either need to (a) draw the whole string at once and let SVG do the spacing, (b) use a non-proportional font like Courier, or (c) go look up the widths of the characters individually.

Comment: hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think the different width of each character is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did (a) at beginning, but I would like the rainbow gradient changing color spreading across letters, so I dropped (a). For (b), I don't want to be tied to any particular font. I prefer (c) if it could be automated. Do you have any idea about how to do it?

Comment: perhaps you should have asked a instead with your code for the gradient.

Comment: @Franva of course, that's always going to be true. But you're still going to have to center the text if you want the spacing that you _can_ effect to look balanced. If you want perfectly identical spacing between the letters, you're going to have to look up the width for each letter, and do the math that places letters not at "i * 12" but at distances based on glyph width for the font you're using. (Because even a monospaced font will has different glyph widths, the visual space between "iii" and "wiw" will be _very_ different).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans glad to try the calculation on width for each letter individually. But that requires to be able to get width of each letter which I do not know. Any idea?

Comment: if you know which font you're using for your site (which you generally do) you can get glyph metrics as a one-time, offline task using something like [ttx](https://fonttools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ttx.html), [fontkit](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit), or even [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js).

Comment: thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans appreciate for providing an alternative way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1:** You may consider using a monospaced font, where each character has the same width. If you want to stick with a proportional font, you can calculate the width of each letter and adjust the x-coordinate accordingly. Here's an example of using a monospaced font:

```
const websiteName = "websitename".split('');

<svg width="180" height="36" style={{ display: "block" }}>
  {websiteName.map((letter, i) => (
    <text x={i * 12} y="30" fontSize="22" fontFamily="monospace" key={i}>
      {letter}
    </text>
  ))}
</svg>
```

**Example 2:** You can calculate the total width of all characters and then distribute the space evenly. Here's an updated version of your code to achieve this:

```
const websiteName = "websitename".split('');

const letterSpacing = 12;
const totalWidth = websiteName.length * letterSpacing;

<svg width={totalWidth} height="36" style={{ display: "block" }}>
  {websiteName.map((letter, i) => (
    <text x={i * letterSpacing} y="30" fontSize="22" key={i}>
      {letter}
    </text>
  ))}
</svg>;
```

Comment: Amazing ~! The 1st approach perfectly solved my problem~! The 2nd approach does not work. As it only put a constant spacing in-between each letter, but still the width of all letters are different, so that's why the 2nd approach does not solve the problem. Btw, I have tried the 2nd example by code.

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?